# Need to change layout of radio buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-widget, radio-button

I've got 2 radio buttons and i want to put them next to each other. Right now theyre like

```
Radio button 1
Radio button 2
```

i want to make it

```
Radio button 1    Radio button 2
```

This is my code for the radio buttons, any help?

```
    <RadioGroup
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_male"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Male" 
      android:layout_below="@id/gender"/>
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_female"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Female" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: What? Your 2 examples of what you want vs what you have are identical.

Answer (score 6):

Did you spend any time on this at all?

Maybe the `android:orientation="vertical"` means something.

Comment: Woah sorry. I cant believe i missed this! Grrrrrrrrrrrr been doing programming all day. i really should take a break! Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

There's no difference in the "before" and "after" layouts as you've written them...

But be that as it may: you have `android:orientation="vertical"` in your XML. Try  `android:orientation="horizontal"`; that should put them on the same line, next to each other.